# Commit charge peak higher than system limit

Tags: windows-server-2003, memory, task-manager

We are seeing some very strange behaviour on our servers and google didn't turn up anything usefull, so I'm tossing it out here.

A standard server is configured with 4GB Ram, 2 4GB pagefiles and running windows server 2003. The servers are running 50-120 vb6/.net applications which normally consume no more than 100mb of memory, but will occasionally run up to 300 mb. The issue with a single process spending way too much memory is being traced down somewhere else, but the thing that is baffling us is that the reported peak charge is vastly higher than what we have available.

[image: Commit charge issue]

As the image above shows, we are getting reported peaks that are way higher than what the system is actually capable of delivering. This number has been seen as high as 29GB, which makes no sense at all for a system with a limit of 12GB.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure none of your pagefiles are set to let Windows manage their size? Because all Windows needs is to know that it can enlarge the page file and it will allow the commit charge to increase.

Comment: They all are, but since we haven't enabled the large page-file option (the name escapes me) they still shouldn't be able to go beyond 4 gb each, however much we would like them to

Comment: Hmm, never mind me, seems like the /PAE flag was set on the particular servers in question. It was only "not set" for the servers where we actually wanted the pagefile to be forced bigger. Can you promote your comment to an answer, so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure none of your pagefiles are set to let Windows manage their size? Because all Windows needs is to know that it can enlarge the page file and it will allow the commit charge to increase.